# Promise is resolving but not triggering .then() function in Node

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Having a problem with getting the then of a function to trigger once a promise is resolved. I can see the resulting html in the `console log` of the nunjucks callback in the code below so I know it's working fine to that point. However nothing is coming back in the `then` of the calling function. 
Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

```
function generate(data, schema, partials) {
  var formTitle = schema.title;


  var defered = q.defer();

  nunjucks.render('test.html', { formTitle: formTitle },function(err, 
html) { 

    if (err) {
      console.log('nunjucks error ', err);
      return defered.reject();
    }
    console.log('nunjucks render ok..', html); // html logging fine here
   // This seems not to work
    q.resolve(html);
  });


  return defered.promise;

}
```

This is the function call.

```
formTemplater.generate(data, schema, {
    header: fs.readFileSync('./header.html', 'utf8'), 
    footer: fs.readFileSync('./footer.html', 'utf8')
}).then(function(html) {
    // nothing works here
    console.log('nunjucks back with html :: ', html);
    fs.writeFileSync('./results.html');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
q.resolve(html)
```

Should be this:

```
defered.resolve(html)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I had tried defered.resolve() before but I think I made a typo so it didn't work ..duh. But tried it again and did the trick. Cheers!